# Resources$NotFoundException thrown after updating Gradle Plugin to 3.4.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.4

I have a project with multiple modules, and after updating to `Gradle Plugin 3.4.0` and `Gradle 5.1.1`, everything else seems to work OK, but the module for `Espresso` tests crashes immediately when trying to run the tests:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.foo:dimen/activity_default_margin with resource ID #0x7f070059
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.foo:dimen/activity_default_margin" (7f070059) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x3201 a=2 r=0x7f070059}
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:786)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:631)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:888)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
  at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:626)
  at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:753)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:196)
  at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
  at com.example.foo.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:160)
```

What could cause this? I first suspected it was R8 being enabled by default starting from 3.4.0, but disabling it didn't help at all. I've cleaned the project multiple times and invalidated caches, and nothing helps.

The `resource ID` is really a dimen resource as it says in the stack trace, and it's only used in a layout which is not even used in the test in question. The crash happens immediately in the test activity's `onCreate()`.

Comment: what is your android studio version ?

Comment: use Clean project and in File->invalidate the cache and restart android studio

Comment: @SandeepMalik 3.4 stable.

Comment: @rajkavadia If you read my question, it says I've tried that multiple times.

Comment: i also try 3.4.0 and after that i also face same problem then i downgrade the version in 3.3.2 then it is working fine

Comment: @manabreak is your issue resolved? im facing the same with appium